# Is it possible to have an internal load balancer with elasticbeanstalk to create a private service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I have an api that I deploy using elasticbeanstalk, and I wish to make it completely internal so that it cannot be accessed from the public Internet. I am doing this because I only want the service to be accessible via our other services (that each run in their own VPCs and are all deployed via elasticbeanstalk).

Is it possible to use an internal ELB with elasticbeanstalk? Is this even what I need to do? Can VPC peering help me here?

The ultimate aim is that the api needs to have some http resources public and some private. My approach was going to be to make the service private and expose any public resources via API Gateway, but perhaps this is not the right solution. Would it perhaps be better to expose everything through API Gateway, require IAM auth on the private resources and enforce in the api that requests come from API Gateway?

Comment: "My approach was going to be to make the service private and expose any public resources via API Gateway". You can only place API Gateway in front of public services. You can lock those services down so that they reject any requests that don't originate from API Gateway, but you can't make them private.

Comment: To elaborate on Mark's comment you would use API Gateway's Client Side SSL certificate feature to ensure only requests from API Gateway are accepted by your service. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It's quite irritating that the API Gateway cannot communicate out of the box with resources in a private subnet. It does appear, however, that this can be done via use of Lambda: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-with-vpc-endpoints-via-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add an ELB to any VPC, including those on private address ranges that are not accessible to the internet.

When configuring your Beanstalk instance, choose an appropriate VPC, unselect "Associate Public IP Address", place an ELB in at least one private subnet and select "Internal" for the ELB visibility.

The VPC configuration page looks like:

[image: VPC Configuration PAge]

Comment: Thanks Alastair, can't believe I didn't see this option!

Comment: If you unselect "Associate Public IP Address", does "ELB visibility" even matter?  Wouldn't the ELB already be inaccessible from the internet.

Comment: @DemPilafian they're not mutually exclusive. You could untick "Associate Public IP Address" but that doesn't prevent you from allocating one later.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Could I make a Beanstalk as Private Service without ELB, only with Single Instance... within the VPC I cannot resolve the URL, I want to use the Beanstalk domain.