# I can't reach the load balancer from within VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a default VPC with 2 Elastic beanstalk applications. I need to call an http endpoint on application A from an instance of Application B. I would like to configure the security group rules of the application A load balancer to accept only incoming http traffic from security group of application B instances.

I tried to add the application B instance security group as a source for the incoming rule on application A load balancer but doesn't work.

I haven't done any particular configuration, I have default VPC and 3 default subnets in 3 availability zones.

Have you any idea?

Comment: Is the load balancer of application A an internal LB or external LB? It would need to be an internal load balancer to work as you describe. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40386845/13070

Comment: I think is an external LB. The load balancer A is reachable from internet through API Gateway and I would like to connect to It from B instances too

Comment: Ah in your question it sounded like you only wanted it accessible to application B and nothing else. Since you want it to also be accessible to the Internet it has to be a public Load Balancer. Since it is a public load balancer your application B has to go out to the Internet and back into AWS to access the Load Balancer. At that point all VPC security group membership information is lost. Are you using a NAT Gateway? You could white-list the IP of the NAT Gateway.

Comment: No, I'm not using any NAT